# Is there a formula to solve these type of questions?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

> The diagram below shows nine circles each tangent to all its neighbours. One of
> the circles is labelled 1. The remaining circles are to be labelled with 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4,
> 4 and 4, such that no two tangent circles have the same label. In how many
> different ways can this be done?

> [image]

Is there a formula to solve these types of questions? If yes, then please share it. It would be of great help.

Sorry if this question turned out to be very easy. I just want to know a formula to solve these questions.

Comment: What do you mean with "a formula"? What kind of variables should be there?

Comment: This is not analytic-geometry. Ii is more similar to graph theory and combinatorics problem. I suppose there is no formula because input data is the structure of graph, which is hard to generalize.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Just wanted to know if there was a formula or not.

Comment: Is $2\times(2+2+2)$ a formula in the sense you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph coloring problem: we construct a graph whose vertices are the balls, and with edges between two vertices whenever their corresponding balls are touching.  Given an $n$-vertex graph, and a size-$n$ multiset of colors, how many vertex colorings of the graph exist using that multiset of colors?

There's likely no simple formula for this general problem, since many [graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) problems are NP-hard.  Although, it's quite possible there's formulas for simple families of graphs.

For a small case like this, we can find the number thusly:

1. we observe that the 1 can only be added to the balls in the bottom corners, so by symmetry, we assume it's the one of the left (and multiply the result by $2$ at the end).
2. we observe the bottom-right corner has three mutually adjacent balls, which implies it must be assigned 2, 3, and 4 (since 1 is already used up), which can be done in [some number] of ways.
3. for each way of assigning 2, 3, and 4 to the bottom-right corner we can complete the assignment in [some number] of ways.

Combining these arguments gives the number.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot